# how to parse JSON file using rest API and spring boot

Tags: json, rest, api, parsing, spring-boot

I'm new to this, and I want to read JSON file imported with rest api and parse it with spring boot.
I worked with CSV file with his method :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/import", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
          String name = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
          System.out.println("File name: "+name);
          byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
          System.out.println("File uploaded content:\n" + new String(bytes));
          return "file uploaded";
      }
```

Now i want to parse a JSON File :

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    },
    {  
        "name":"Mark",
        "city":"Oslo",
        "cars":[  
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
        ],
        "job":"Doctor"
    }
]
```

I have try it to parse this file with java and it works for me but I dont know how to get it with rest api

This method to parse te file JSON and it works

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
    IOException, ParseException {

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(
        "D:/PFE 2018/testjsonfile.json"));

for (Object o : jsonArray) {
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

    String strName = (String) person.get("name");
    System.out.println("Name::::" + strName);

    String strCity = (String) person.get("city");
    System.out.println("City::::" + strCity);

    JSONArray arrays = (JSONArray) person.get("cars");
    for (Object object : arrays) {
        System.out.println("cars::::" + object);
    }
    String strJob = (String) person.get("job");
    System.out.println("Job::::" + strJob);
    System.out.println();

}

}
```

now  how to reuse this methode with rest api

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with your JSON (it's not entirely clear in your question).
In general, good practice with Spring Boot is to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/blob/master/README.md) either:

- binding your JSON with a POJO if you expect your JSON to have a known format or
- mapping your JSON in a tree.

Examples for the described behaviours can be found in [this article](https://springframework.guru/processing-json-jackson/) for instance.

Comment: thank you, I want to read this JSON file, parse it to an object to inject it in the database

Comment: Ok, so my answer is what you're looking for as practice. If you have already a Java object then it's normally a POJO and you want the first method.

Comment: Can I do it without POJO class ? i  already parse it  you can show it in the question i update it  but nnow i want to insert the file with rest api multipart file and then parse it ?

Comment: Alright, then instead of using import, etc... You can get the object from the REST call and use Jackson to convert it into a tree (method 2),that won't require a POJO and you'll have a tree object easily parseable.